Snowflake to Delta Lake incremental synchronisation
I'm trying to come up with a way of reconstituting a Snowflake table in Delta format by incrementally processing change data. My attempt so far involves creating a Stream over a table and a Task to periodically execute a 'COPY INTO' statement which writes offsets from the Stream into an External Stage in csv format. From Databricks, the cloud storage location of the External Stage is registered as an External Volume and is monitored using a file-triggered workflow which contains an AutoLoader DLT pipeline.
This kind-of works in the bronze layer - the csv data is consumed and appended to a target Delta table without issue, but the metadata produced by the stream doesn't include a timestamp or sequence identifier to indicate the order that the actions were performed in - so it's impossible to recreate the table as it appears at source.
Is there a better way of creating incremental ingestion pipelines from Snowflake into Delta Lake?
[Snowflake] Create table
CREATE TABLE books (
  id NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL autoincrement start 1 increment 1 noorder,
  title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  published_year INTEGER,
  genre VARCHAR(50)
);

[Snowflake] Create stream
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM BOOKS_STREAM ON TABLE BOOKS
SHOW_INITIAL_ROWS = TRUE;

[Snowflake] Create task
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK UNLOAD_TASK 
WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
AS 
COPY INTO @my_external_stage
FROM (SELECT * FROM BOOKS_STREAM) 
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE='CSV' COMPRESSION = NONE)
INCLUDE_QUERY_ID = TRUE
HEADER = TRUE;

[Databricks] Create Live Table
@dlt.table("books_bronze", temporary=False)
def books_bronze_ingest():
  return (spark
    .readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", schemaPath)
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .load(<same-path-as-external-stage>)


I may be missing the point of your question but why not just add current_timestamp() as an extra column in SELECT * FROM BOOKS_STREAM?

Thanks for your response @NickW - One question, what if a single row had changed multiple times between task invocations... wouldn't the change feed list multiple changes with the same row id but the same timestamp?

I wasn't sure so I ran a test in which I updated the same row twice and then consumed the stream's offsets (with the additional CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() column) and the resulting change feed included two change records pertaining to the same row, unfortunately with the same timestamp, so there's no way to determine the sequence unfortunately :/ thank you for the suggestion anyway :)

When you read a stream it will only return the current state of a record, not a row for every individual update that may have been made to a record since the stream was last consumed.

If you update a row's values using SET, the stream produces two rows - one where METADATA$ACTION equals DELETE and another where METADATA$ACTION equals INSERT.

That's correct, but that's because an UPDATE is actually an INSERT and a DELETE in Snowflake (kinda).  So you just use the INSERT record as your new record.  NickW's solution is correct.  Also, would it be easier to simply use Iceberg Tables instead of what you are doing?  Both platforms use it seamlessly.

Thanks @NickW and @Mike Walton for your help - as you rightly say, owing to the fact that Streams report only the present state of changed rows at the point in time that the stream is queried, you can simply add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() to the COPY INTO task like so;
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK UNLOAD_TASK 
WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
AS 
COPY INTO @my_external_stage
FROM (SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS INGESTION_TIMESTAMP FROM BOOKS_STREAM) 
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE='CSV' COMPRESSION = NONE)
INCLUDE_QUERY_ID = TRUE
HEADER = TRUE;

From Databricks, you can load this into a bronze Delta Table using DLT like so;
@dlt.table("books_bronze", temporary=False)
def books_bronze_ingest():
  return (spark
    .readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
    .option("cloudFiles.inferColumnTypes", True)
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", schemaPath)
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .load(<same-path-as-external-stage>)

Snowflake represents UPDATE operations as a DELETE followed by an INSERT action. The INSERT describes the target state of the update, meaning that you need not process the DELETE row. You can discard it in an intermediary DLT view like so;
@dlt.view
def books_brass():
    return dlt.sql("""
        SELECT *
        FROM books_bronze
        WHERE NOT(METADATA$ACTION = 'DELETE' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE = true)
    """)

Finally, to reconstruct the table as it appears at source, you can use DLT's APPLY CHANGES INTO statement;
dlt.create_streaming_table("books_silver")
dlt.apply_changes(
    target = "books_silver",
    source = "books_brass",
    keys = ["METADATA$ROW_ID"],
    sequence_by = col("INGESTION_TIMESTAMP"),
    apply_as_deletes = expr("METADATA$ACTION = 'DELETE' AND METADATA$ISUPDATE = false")
)

Run in continuous mode, you can synchronise Snowflake and Delta tables in near realtime, or you can make use of file arrival triggered workflows for event-driven processing.
(At the time of writing I don't have access to Databricks or Snowflake so please excuse any small inaccuracies in the code!)
